# Can $pk+1$ divide $(p-k)^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Let $p>3$ be a prime, $0<k<p$. Then is it possible that $pk+1\mid(p-k)^2$?

For $k=1$, since $(p-1)^2\equiv(-2)^2\equiv4\pmod{p+1}$, and $p>3$, this is not possible.

And if $pk+1\mid(p-k)^2$ then $k^2-3pk+p^2-1\geq0$, so $k\leq\frac{3p-\sqrt{5p^2+4}}2$.

---

This arises from another question. I am running out of ideas, so any help is sincerely appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: How about polynomial division?

Comment: So you divide $p^2 - 2pk + k^2$ by $pk + 1$.

Comment: Do you mean division in $\mathbb Q[X]$? But how can this show divisibility in $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: I meant to say that you might be able to use polynomial division to obtain conditions on $p, k$ under which your required divisibility constraint holds.

Comment: FWIW brute forcing with Mathematica (barring a programming error from me) tells that there are no solutions when $p$ is among the 1000 smallest primes.

Comment: Without the assumption that $p$ is prime, there are solutions.  For example, if $F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number ($F_0=0$, $F_1=1$, and $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ for all $n\geq 2$), then $(p,k)=(F_{2n+2},F_{2n})$ works for all $n> 0$.  Unfortunately, $F_{2n}$ is not prime for all $n\geq 3$.

Comment: Fix a positive integer $t$.  There are also solutions of the form $(p,k)=(a_{n+1},a_n)$, where $a_0=0$, $a_1=t$, and $a_n=(t^2+2)a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$ for $n\geq 2$.  If $t=1$, we end up with the even Fibonacci sequence as in the comment above.  If $t>1$, then $t$ divides all $a_n$, so unfortunately, this sequence does not produce $(p,k)=(a_{n+1},a_n)$ in which $p$ is prime either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Claim:** If $a,b$ are positive integers and $q(a,b) := \frac{(a-b)^2}{ab+1}$ is an integer, it is a square number. This may be proved by Vieta jumping as follows:

Let $k \geqslant 1$ be an integer, which is not a square. Assume that there are positive integers $A,B$ such that $q(A,B) = k$, and choose $A$ and $B$ so that $A \geqslant B$ and that $A+B$ is minimal.

By expanding the statement $q(A,B) = k$, we find that $A$ is a solution to the quadratic $X^2 - B(2+k)X + B^2 - k = 0$. Since its discriminant is positive, there is another solution $C$ which may be expressed using Vieta's formulas as

\begin{align*}
C = B(2+k) - A = \frac{B^2 - k}{A} < A.
\end{align*}
The first representation of $C$ shows that it's an integer, and the other one shows that it's non-zero, since $k$ isn't a square. Also, since 
\begin{align*}
\frac{(C-B)^2 }{CB + 1} = k > 0,
\end{align*}
we see that $C$ has to be a *positive* integer. But then 
\begin{align*}
C+ B < A+B,
\end{align*}
contradicting the minimality of $A+B$.   $\blacksquare$

This means that if $q(p,t)$ is an integer, there is some integer $m$ with

\begin{align*}
q(p,t) = \frac{(p-t)^2}{pt + 1} = m^2,
\end{align*}
and by estimating $q(p,t)$ (using $1 \leqslant t \leqslant p-1$) it's easy to see that $m^2 \leqslant p-1$. 
Rearranging this equation gives 
\begin{align*}
p^2 - 2pt + t^2 = m^2 p t + m^2,
\end{align*}
so 
\begin{align*}
p \mid p^2 - (2 + m^2) p t  = m^2 - t^2 = (m-t)(m+t).
\end{align*}
Given the bounds on $m$ and $t$, the only possibilities here are that $m = t$ or that $m+t = p$. In the first case, our equation is
\begin{align*}
p^2 - 2pt + t^2 = t^3 p + t^2 &\Leftrightarrow p^2 - 2pt - t^3 p = 0 \\
&\Leftrightarrow p  = 2t + t^3
\end{align*}
so $t \mid p$, meaning $t = 1$, so $p = 3$, which is impossible. In the second case, we have $m = p-t$, so our equation is
\begin{align*}
(p-t)^2 = p^2 - 2pt + t^2 = (p-t)^2 p t + (p-t)^2 &\Leftrightarrow 1 = pt + 1,
\end{align*}
forcing $t = 0$, which is impossible.

Comment: I think the last equation is more clearly seen as $(p-t)^2=\frac{(p-t)^2}{1+pt}\implies t=0$. And $t\mid p$ is possible if $p$ can be $3$: If $t=1$, then $p=3$. Thanks for this ingenious proof!

Comment: No problem! Thanks for pointing out the subtlety in the case p=3. I'll edit to include this

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $p$ and $k$ are integers such that $p>k>0$ and $$n=\frac{(p-k)^2}{pk+1}$$
for some integer $n>0$.  Note that $(x,y)=(p,k)$ is a solution to the quadratic equation
$$x^2+y^2-(n+2)xy=n.\tag{1}$$
Let $(x,y)=(a,b)$ be a solution to (1) such that $a>b>0$ and $a+b$ takes the smallest possible value.  We claim that $n=b^2$.

Observe that $$(x,y)=\big(b,(n+2)b-a\big)=\left(b,\frac{b^2-n}{a}\right)\tag{2}$$
is an integer solution to (1), but not necessarily positive.  If $b^2>n$, then we see that (2) gives an integer solution in which
$$b>\frac{b^2-n}{a}>0\text{ and }b+\frac{b^2-n}{a}<a+b.$$
This contradicts the assumption that $a+b$ is minimum.  Hence, $b^2\leq n$.

If $b^2<n$, then observe that 
$$(x,y)=\left(\frac{b^2-n}{a},\frac{b^2-n}{a}(n+2)-b\right)=\left(\frac{b^2-n}{a},\frac{\left(\frac{b^2-n}{a}\right)^2-n}{b}\right)$$
is another integer solution to (1), with both numbers being negative.  Since (1) is invariant under the assignment $(x,y)\mapsto (-y,-x)$, we see that
$$(x,y)=\left(\frac{n-b^2}{a}(n+2)+b,\frac{n-b^2}{a}\right)$$
is a positive integer solution with
$$\frac{n-b^2}{a}(n+2)+b>\frac{n-b^2}{a}>0.$$
By minimality of $a+b$, we must have
$$\left(\frac{n-b^2}{a}(n+2)+b\right)+\frac{n-b^2}{a}\geq a+b.$$
Hence,
$$n(n+3)\geq a^2+(n+3)b^2.$$
Recall from (2) that
$$(n+2)b-a=\frac{b^2-a}{n}<0.$$
That is, $a>(n+2)b$ and we get
$$\begin{align}n(n+3)&\geq a^2+(n+3)b^2>(n+2)^2b^2+(n+3)b^2\\&\geq (n+2)^2+(n+3)=n(n+3)+(2n+7)>n(n+3).\end{align}$$
This is a contradiction, so $n=b^2$ is the only possibility.

With $n=b^2$, (2) becomes $(x,y)=\big(b,(b^2+2)b-a\big)=(b,0)$, so
$$a=b(b^2+2).$$
Note also that
$$(x,y)=\big((b^2+2)p-k,p\big)=\left(\frac{p^2-n}{k},p\right)$$
is also an integer solution to (1) satisfying $x>y>0$, provided that $(x,y)=(p,k)$ is a solution to (1) with $p>k>0$.  Indeed, we can see that all integer solutions $(x,y)=(p,k)$ with $n=b^2$  satisfying $p>k>0$ are given by
$$(p,k)=(t_{j+1},t_j)$$
for some positive integer $t_j$.  Here, we define $t_0=0$, $t_1=b$, and
$$t_j=(b^2+2)t_{j-1}-t_{j-2}$$
for $j\geq 2$.  Note that $t_j$ is divisible by $b$ at all $j$.  Since $t_j>b$ for $j>1$, we conclude that $p$ is not prime when $b>1$.

For $b=1$, however, $t_j=F_{2j}$ (where $\left(F_m\right)$ is the Fibonacci sequence).  Since $F_j$ divides $F_{2j}$ for all $j$ and $F_j>1$ for $j>2$, we conclude that $p$ is prime only when $p=F_4=3$.

Comment: How do you prove that all integer solutions $(x,y)=(p,k)$ with $n=b^2$ satisfying $p>k>0$ are given in the specified form? Also, the statement $n=b^2$ can also be obtained by the method of @TeddantheTerran: in the notations there, it corresponds to the case $m=t$. Thanks for the answer still. :-)

Comment: Starting with $(x,y)=(p,k)$.  You can show that the repeated iterations $(x,y)\mapsto \big(y,(b^2+2)y-x\big)$ will always terminate at $(x,y)=(b,0)$.  So $(x,y)=(p,k)$ can be obtained by repeated iterations $(x,y)\mapsto \big((b^2+2)x-y,x\big)$ starting from $(x,y)=(b,0)$.